# Module "Qt.labs.controls" is not installed

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I am trying to run my Qt Quick application on embedded devices. But it says "Qt.labs.controls" is not installed.

I installed `qml-module-qtquick-controls` `qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel` and `qml-module-qt-labs-settings` but it does not solve the problem.

Does anyone know what I need? Thanks in advance

Comment: Which platform is it? What is the Qt version? Is there any package called `qml-module-qt-labs-controls`, `qml-module-qtquick-controls2`, or similar?

Comment: You need to paste here the whole error message.